ValueError: Invalid value for attribute `regularizer`. Expected an instance of `keras.regularizers.Regularizer`, or `None`
I downloaded a lung cancer prediction model and tried to use it but it gave me the error in the title. It says that the error is in a line in which I don't see any parameters for regularizers.
tr_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function= scalar,
                            horizontal_flip= True)

# Create an ImageDataGenerator for training with specified preprocessing and augmentation settings
tr_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar, horizontal_flip=True)

# Create an ImageDataGenerator for testing with specified preprocessing settings
ts_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar)

# Generate a flow from DataFrame for training data
train_gen = tr_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df,
    x_col='Image_Path',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=img_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode=color,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=batch_size
)

# Generate a flow from DataFrame for validation data
valid_gen = ts_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    valid_df,
    x_col='Image_Path',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=img_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode=color,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=batch_size
)

# Generate a flow from DataFrame for test data
test_gen = ts_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    test_df,
    x_col='Image_Path',
    y_col='Label',
    target_size=img_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode=color,
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=test_batch_size
)

# Using the EfficientNetB5 pre-trained model as a base model (without the fully connected layers)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.EfficientNetB5(
    include_top=False,     # Exclude the fully connected layers
    weights="imagenet",    # Load pre-trained ImageNet weights
    input_shape=img_shape,  # Specify the input shape for the model
    pooling='max'           # Use global max pooling as the final pooling layer
)

# Constructing the complete model using Sequential API
model = Sequential([
    base_model,  # EfficientNetB5 as the base model
    BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001),  # Batch normalization layer
    Dense(256,
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.016),
          activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
          bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
          activation='relu'),  # Dense layer with regularization and ReLU activation
    Dropout(rate=0.45, seed=123),  # Dropout layer for regularization
    Dense(4, activation='softmax')  # Output layer with softmax activation for multi-class classification
])

# Compile the model with specified optimizer, loss function, and evaluation metric
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adamax(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Display a summary of the model architecture
model.summary()


# Define early stopping to halt training if the validation loss doesn't improve for 'patience' consecutive epochs
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                           patience=5,
                           verbose=1)
# Define model checkpoint to save the best weights during training based on validation loss
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_weights_efficient_B5_2.h5',
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=True,
                             mode='min',
                             verbose=1)

# Train the EfficientNetB5 base model on the training data with validation using the generator
# - x: Training generator
# - steps_per_epoch: Number of batches to process in each epoch
# - epochs: Number of training epochs
# - callbacks: List of callbacks to apply during training (early stopping and model checkpoint)
# - validation_data: Validation generator for evaluating the model's performance on a separate dataset

history = model.fit(x= train_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch = 20,
                    epochs= 100,
                    callbacks=[early_stop, checkpoint],
                    validation_data = valid_gen)

It gave me the error at the end on the line:
history = model.fit(x= train_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch = 20,
                    epochs= 100,
                    callbacks=[early_stop, checkpoint],
                    validation_data = valid_gen)

this is what the output is supposed to be,
Epoch 1/100
2024-01-09 05:09:14.022849: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:954] layout failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Size of values 0 does not match size of permutation 4 @ fanin shape insequential/efficientnetb5/block1b_drop/dropout/SelectV2-2-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.0968 - accuracy: 0.6117
Epoch 1: val_loss improved from inf to 12.97059, saving model to model_weights_efficient_B5_2.h5
20/20 [==============================] - 111s 1s/step - loss: 9.0968 - accuracy: 0.6117 - val_loss: 12.9706 - val_accuracy: 0.4028
Epoch 2/100
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0688 - accuracy: 0.8091
Epoch 2: val_loss improved from 12.97059 to 9.59253, saving model to model_weights_efficient_B5_2.h5
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 701ms/step - loss: 8.0688 - accuracy: 0.8091 - val_loss: 9.5925 - val_accuracy: 0.5278
Epoch 3/100
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.3052 - accuracy: 0.9331
Epoch 3: val_loss improved from 9.59253 to 8.73472, saving model to model_weights_efficient_B5_2.h5
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 704ms/step - loss: 7.3052 - accuracy: 0.9331 - val_loss: 8.7347 - val_accuracy: 0.5139
...
Epoch 73: val_loss did not improve from 0.97909
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 667ms/step - loss: 0.7622 - accuracy: 0.9951 - val_loss: 0.9830 - val_accuracy: 0.9028
Epoch 74/100
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7229 - accuracy: 0.9967
Epoch 74: val_loss did not improve from 0.97909
20/20 [==============================] - 14s 668ms/step - loss: 0.7229 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 1.0451 - val_accuracy: 0.9028
Epoch 74: early stopping


this is what I received,
{
    "name": "ValueError",
    "message": "Invalid value for attribute `regularizer`. Expected an instance of `keras.regularizers.Regularizer`, or `None`. Received: regularizer=<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L2 object at 0x0000022E00215070>",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 20
      6 checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_weights_efficient_B5_2.h5',
      7                              monitor='val_loss',
      8                              save_best_only=True,
      9                              save_weights_only=True,
     10                              mode='min',
     11                              verbose=1)
     13 # Train the EfficientNetB5 base model on the training data with validation using the generator
     14 # - x: Training generator
     15 # - steps_per_epoch: Number of batches to process in each epoch
     16 # - epochs: Number of training epochs
     17 # - callbacks: List of callbacks to apply during training (early stopping and model checkpoint)
     18 # - validation_data: Validation generator for evaluating the model's performance on a separate dataset
---> 20 history = model.fit(x=train_gen,
     21                     steps_per_epoch = 20,
     22                     epochs= 100,
     23                     callbacks=[early_stop, checkpoint],
     24                     validation_data = valid_gen)

File c:\\Users\\thien\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File c:\\Users\\thien\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\common\\variables.py:304, in KerasVariable.regularizer(self, value)
    301 from keras.src.regularizers import Regularizer
    303 if value is not None and not isinstance(value, Regularizer):
--> 304     raise ValueError(
    305         \"Invalid value for attribute `regularizer`. Expected an \"
    306         \"instance of `keras.regularizers.Regularizer`, or `None`. \"
    307         f\"Received: regularizer={value}\"
    308     )
    309 self._regularizer = value

ValueError: Invalid value for attribute `regularizer`. Expected an instance of `keras.regularizers.Regularizer`, or `None`. Received: regularizer=<tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers.L2 object at 0x0000022E00215070>"
}

Edit 1: this is the way I imported the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


import os
import random

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import cv2

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras._tf_keras.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras._tf_keras.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras._tf_keras.keras.optimizers import Adam, Adamax
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras._tf_keras.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Activation, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.python.keras.regularizers import l1, l2

It looks messy because in the original file, I couldn't get it to work because of some problems so I had to switch to keras._tf_keras for some imports. That might be the reason but I still don't know how to fix it. Here is the original:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


import os
import random

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import cv2

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, Adamax
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Activation, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1, l2

Hope this edit helps

Can you share how you import the libraries? As a rule of thumb, it's good to avoid mixing keras and tf.keras

@Lescurel I edited it, if you could check it please do, thanks in advance!

Try to install keras==2.15 with tensorflow==2.15 with the original imports.

It gives me this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.15 (from versions: 2.16.0rc0, 2.16.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.15

I'm guessing you're using python 3.12. Try to downgrade your python version to 3.11

Still not working, I also found out that ImageDataGenerator is deprecated so might that be the cause?

No, this should not be related. As I said in my first comment, yor problem probably comes from mixing keras and tf.keras

No real solution, but I tested your code and your original imports of TF 2.16.1/Keras 3.3.3 and TF 2.15.1/Keras 2.15.0 and it runs on both versions (minus minor errors). As Lescurel said, sounds like a version miss-match of packages. Try pip install --force-reinstall tensorflow and check in the output if keras was also reinstalled. Otherwise do also pip install -f keras. This should reinstall the newest versions of TF/Keras. Hope it helps.
